# T-SQL Bulk insert not sorting first row at the top

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

The intention of the below script is to BULK INSERT from a file and always retrieve the first row of the File.csv because I need the column names that reside in the first row.

Here's an example of the file contents

```
SiteCode,ItemCode
1,ABC
2,DSG
1,TGB
```

As you can see this file is comma delimited, and therefore the desired output of the below BULK INSERT script should be "SiteCode,ItemCode" without quotes.
File.csv has a ROWTERMINATOR of CRLF and the encoding is UTF-8.

The below script works perfectly with files that have smaller number of rows, however, it intermittently does not return the column headings (first row) when there are more rows.
For example, if you take a file with the same structure as in the example above but with 2462 rows the desired output will work every time the script is run.

However, adding just 1 additional row to make it 2463 rows will NOT return the first row every time the script is run. The weird thing is, almost like clockwork, it will produce the desired result 5 times and fail every 6th time

Here is the simple BULK INSERT script

```
CREATE TABLE StagingFirstRow (RowData NVARCHAR(MAX));

BULK INSERT StagingFirstRow
FROM 'C:\TEST\File.csv'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0D0A',
    CODEPAGE = '65001',
    FIRSTROW = 1
)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM StagingFirstRow
DROP TABLE StagingFirstRow
```

This is of course a simplified version of my script - My original script iterates through multiple files that I need retrieve column names from but I was still able to produce the issue with the basic script above.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?
All I need is to retrieve the first row of the file (which is the column headings) every single time the script it run.

Comment: Does it work if you add `, LASTROW = 1` to the bulk call so you only get one?

Comment: @siggemannen bro! you are a legend. That worked, I didn't even know LASTROW was a thing. I'm surprised chatGPT couldn't even help me with such a simple suggestion. Thank you

Comment: A table is an unordered set of rows regardless of the method used to insert data and the order rows are inserted. An ORDER BY clause in the query to return data in a particular order so it seems you need an additional column to denote header rows versus data data if you need the header data returned first by a query.

Comment: Glad it worked. I just read the manual :)

Comment: *"I'm surprised chatGPT couldn't even help me with such a simple suggestion."* There are many who aren't. ;)

Comment: Unrelated but maybe use `FORMAT=CSV`